# How is the notion that gases expand to the containing volume fit with the concept of molar volume?

Tags: gas-laws, ideal-gas

I have a question about the concept of molar volume of a gas, which is defined as the volume occupied per mole of molecules of the gas.

I don't know details about what a gas is at a deep level, but from high school level knowledge, gases expand to fill the volume they are contained in.

If we have one mole of a gas in a balloon in a huge room at sea level at a location at some standard temperature (0 degrees C), and we release the gas from the balloon, what can we say about the volume the gas will occupy? Is it really the molar volume?

How does that go with the notion that a gas expands because molecules are moving very fast and chaotically at a relatively large distance from each other?

I can understand intuitively, from everyday experience, what a molar volume of a liquid would be (at specific conditions of temperature and atmospheric pressure), because I can see the liquid and how much volume it occupies.

Does the same thing occur with gases? If we have a gas that is red, will it have a fixed volume (the molar volume)?

Comment: For ideal gas: $$V_\mathrm{m} = \frac{V}{n} = \frac{RT}{p}.$$  Not to be confused with the own volume of $\pu{1 mol}$ of real gas molecules, with is very roughly 1/4 of $b$ parameter of [van der Waals's real gas state  equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation)  (Less roughly for monoatomic gases, as the model assumes spherical molecules)

Comment: The confusion might come form comparing with molar mass (a constant for a given substance). Molar volume depends on the pressure and whether your gas is mixed with other gases. It is not a constant for a given substance. In my experience, complaining about downvotes leads to more downvotes. Improving the question, integrating what you learned from the comments, and asking for help improving the question are strategies that have been successful.

Comment: Related (thanks Mithoron): https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/105324

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The gas laws define relationships under fixed conditions: molar volume is defined when all the other variables are fixed**

The confusion you have seems to result from failing to consider the conditions under which molar volume is defined.

The ideal gas laws define the relationship between 4 things: the volume, the pressure, the temperature and the amount of molecules of the gas. Al sorts of combinations of those variables are possible. If the amount of gas molecules is constant (say 1 mole of the gas molecules) there are still 3 variables to play with. So there are plenty of combinations of volume, pressure and temperature are possible. Even if temperature is fixed, there are still a range of combinations of volume and pressure where the law will be satisfied.

But if the pressure is also fixed, there is only one possible volume where the law works. This is the *molar volume* (the volume occupied when everything else if fixed).

There is no contradiction between this definition and the fact that a gas whose volume is *unconstrained* will fill all the space available. But that case has too many free variable for a single volume to make sense (both the volume and the partial pressure can vary freely).

The case where molar volume does make sense is one where the *pressure* is held constant (imagine a vessel with a plunger that exerts a constant pressure in the vessel's contents. If that pressure is fixed, then the volume of a mole of gas released into the (empty) vessel will be the molar volume. And that volume will be the same for any gas (if far enough away from the point where it ceases to be an ideal gas).

Answer (score 1):

For the air as mixture, one may consider the molar volume as the volume containing $\pu{1 mol}$ of any molecules $$V_\mathrm{M, air}=\frac{RT}{p_\mathrm{air}}.$$

For just the $\pu{1 mol}$ of the gas from the balloon, the molar volume is determined by the partial pressure of the gas $$V_\mathrm{M,gas}=\frac{RT}{p_\mathrm{gas}}.$$

And

$$p_\mathrm{gas} = \frac{n_\mathrm{gas}RT}{V_\mathrm{container}},$$

as the gas molar volume is equal to the container volume

In both cases, we can assume ideal gas behavior with negligible errors.

Comment: I am trying to get an intuitive idea of the concept of molar mass. The formulas are available online, but again, how do we reconcile the common but perhaps imprecise idea that a gas "expands" with the notion that it occupies a determined volume for a given amount of molecules?

Comment: Intuition and definition do not like each other. I do not see gas expansion in any controversy with definition of the molar mass.

Comment: No one said there was a contradiction. I don't know what you mean by "intuition and definition do not like each other", but my intuition tells me that that comment is very, very, very wrong. Intuitive notions can help one to understand definitions enormously. In that sense, I would say definition loves intuition. I can give you many examples in mathematics and physics. And the converse is true too, an intuitive notion loves to achieve the precise pinning down that a definition might offer.

Comment: Just look at the accepted answer. There are no formulas there, but rather an intuitive explanation of the formulas.

Comment: @evianpring Definitions are deliberately chosen relations between terms and their meanings. I would not describe verbose description as intuition. Intuition does not work with descriptions. Intuition does not need descriptions. Intuition just "knows"  that A is X.  But it cannot know if I have defined A is X or not.

Comment: What you are describing as intuition is called memorization, and it is not how understanding is obtained. Knowing is different from understanding. And understanding is helped by descriptions, didactical explanations, visuals/graphics, etc. Let me give you a very simple example: you can learn about matrix multiplication in high school and spend your entire life "knowing" how to do it but never having the insights about vector spaces contained in matrices. Therefore, you will never have intuition in all the places where matrices are applied.

Comment: Once you learn about vector spaces and linear combinations and someone explains to you that matrix columns and rows can be viewed as vectors, you look at a matrix and see a column space, a row space, a null space, etc. You can't unsee it anymore and so you have an intuitive understanding of what it means to do a matrix multiplication. The formulas don't matter anymore as much as your ability to recreate the formulas from your understanding of what is really happening. So, the original question was: what is really happening in this concept of molar volume? I know the formula. Is there insight?

Comment: You did not provide any of the latter. But the accepted answer did, and now I can see what was missing in my understanding initially, and my understanding has been augmented. The intuition is, as explained, that the ideal gas laws define a relationship between four things, and if we fix two of them (pressure and temperature) and then fix a third (1 mol), then because of the ideal gas law equation, volume is pinned down. From this point forward, my intuition about these variables will involve thinking in these terms.

Comment: @evianpring No, intuition as I understand it is nothing like memorization. It is guessing the right answer with some level of probability/confidence without exact knowledge how to get this answer. // I have just very recently, today or yesterday, in other question explained the ideal gas state equation is the system with 3 degrees of freedom, leading to 1 of 4 variables depending on the other 3.  // It is quite possible that we talk each about different kind of intuition. One is less than knowledge, the other more than knowledge.